# How can I use object initializer to declare and initialize the variable in the sample below?

Tags: c#, variables, delegates, declaration

I am trying to declare and initialize a variable using object initializer but am having trouble but the line in Main() is giving me the error "Cannot use a variable before it's declared". If I remove it, it will complain saying Conditions is nowhere to be found. Is this possible to use object initializer for this?

```
class Program
{  
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = new Trigger<GameEvent>
        {
            Event = () => EventMessenger.Instance.AddListener<GameEvent>(t.Conditions)
        };
    }
}

public class Trigger<T>
{
    public Action Event { get; set; }
    public void Conditions() {} 
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code - it is impossible to read

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was downvoted? Title is clear and straight to the point, code provided shows only the necessary info. No such question was found on stackoverflow.

Comment: Generally it is good idea to read on error message (like CS0841 in this case, possibly finding this article - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c.aspx in addition to regular MSDN error description) and show you research in the question. Also "must be one line" comments felt like trolling and people could simple voted down your question (in addition to original questionable formatting).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the variable you are declaring in its initializer.

```
static void Main()
{
    var t = new Trigger<GameEvent>(null);
    t.eventX = () => EventMessenger.Instance.AddListener<GameEvent>(t.Conditions());
}
```

`Conditions` is also a method, *not* a variable/property, so you must refer to it using `t.Conditions()`.

Comment: Yes I know, but the questions is HOW can I do it all in one line.

Comment: Here is how `var t = new Trigger<GameEvent>(null);t.eventX = () => EventMessenger.Instance.AddListener<GameEvent>(t.Conditions());`

Comment: Well the answer is you can't. You cannot use an object before it is declared.

Comment: Why one line? (what do you want to achieve?)

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler "you can't" is perfectly valid answer. Obviously you can wrap that code in helper function to have "one statement" version, but I don't think it make it any different. If you want to do something similar I'd recommend reading [anonymous recursion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx) to see how far you can push it...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that's not one line.

Comment: Siriam's solution is two statements on **one line**!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "you can't" is a valid answer, yes. I think I have my answer now.
Cyral doesn't have to. I was just curious to know if I was missing something. I usually use object initialize to initialize my objects and have never ran into any problems until now.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler That's indeed one line. You never said one statement. You said one line and it is. To get a constructive answer ask constructive question please. Why on earth it has to be one line?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it doesn't have to be one line, just in one go using object initializer. Also you are not using object initializer to fully initialize the variable as the question asked in your solution.